# Permission denied (publickey) error when cloning submodule in Jenkins agent

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, bitbucket, git-submodules

I have a Jenkins setup where I have a master node that runs my jobs successfully. However, I am trying to add a Jenkins agent to the setup. The agent machine is unable to clone a submodule from Bitbucket into its local machine. I keep encountering the following error: "Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

Here's the workflow I'm following:

1. On the Jenkins master, I have configured the necessary credentials (SSH key pair) for accessing the Bitbucket repository.
2. after cloning the repo i am running this following command `git submodule update --init --recursive`
3. The job runs successfully on the master node, and the submodule is cloned without any issues.
4. Now, I want to run the same job on the Jenkins agent machine, but it fails with the "Permission denied (publickey)" error when attempting to clone the submodule.

I have already tried the following troubleshooting steps, but none of them resolved the issue:

1. Checked that the SSH keys are correctly added to the SSH agent on the Jenkins agent machine.
2. Verified that the Jenkins agent has the necessary read/write permissions on the directory where the submodule is being cloned.
3. Tried manually make a connection to the submodule repository and it worked. I can see in the bitbucket UI that the new key has been used after I run this command on the machine but when i clone it is stiil the same error
4. i also changed the agent home directory to `/var/lib/jenkins` and the key is in`/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa`

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and enable the Jenkins agent to clone the submodule successfully. Any insights, suggestions, or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any more detail in that message?

Comment: hey this is the full log 
"""+ git submodule update --init --recursive
Cloning into '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/...'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
"""
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.